# ¿Cómo cifrar y descifrar un archivo protegido con contraseña usando PGP?

Tags: linux, unix, gpg

Suponiendo que tengo un archivo de texto llamado `prueba.txt`.

```
Hola
```

Y lo cifro con GPG de la siguiente manera:

```
$ gpg -c prueba.txt
```

Esto me pide una contraseña y después me genera el archivo `prueba.txt.gpg`. Ahora si quisiera descifrar el archivo tendría que hacer lo siguiente:

```
$ gpg --decrypt prueba.txt.gpg
```

Lo cual debería pedirme la contraseña del archivo para poder descrifrarlo, pero no lo hace. Sólo lo descifra sin ninguna contraseña.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto puede ser comportamiento normal, `gpg` ahora usa `gpg-agent` para gestionar claves privadas, y el agente almacena las claves en caché durante un cierto tiempo (hasta dos horas por defecto, con un tiempo de inactividad de diez minutos). Lo cual significa que durante ese tiempo no se te solicitará la contraseña para desencriptar.

Para cambiar los valores predeterminados, crea o edite un archivo llamado `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` y utiliza las siguientes entradas:

- **`default-cache-ttl`** especifica la cantidad de tiempo que se guarda una entrada de caché después de su último uso, en segundos (`600` por defecto);
- **`max-cache-ttl`** especifica la cantidad máxima de tiempo que se mantiene una entrada de caché, en segundos (`7200` por defecto).

Después de cambiarlos, necesitaras recargar la configuración (intenta enviar un `SIGHUP` a `gpg-agent`, o matarlo directamente con `kill gpg-agent`).

Fuente: [gpg does not ask for password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395876/235922)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Hasta tuve que comprobar con otra computadora que el archivo no estuviera dañado o algo similar.